# Check if item already exists in json array by matching ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

So I've this shopping cart, as JSON.

```
[{"tuote":{"id":"2","name":"Rengas 2","count":16,"price":"120.00"}},{"tuote":{"id":"1","name":"Rengas 6","count":"4","price":"25.00"}},{"tuote":{"id":"4","name":"Rengas 4","count":"4","price":"85.00"}}]
```

[Formatted here.](http://pastebin.com/dBZ6Lq8s)

So, I want to prevent from having the same value in there twice, and match them by their `id`s.

This is my current solution (buggy as a cockroach, doesn't really do the job), as the only time it works is when the matching value is first in the JSON string.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ostoskori.length; i++) {

    if (ostoskori[i].tuote.id == tuoteID) {
        addToExisting(tuoteID, tuoteMaara); //this doesn't matter, it works.
        break //the loop should stop if addToExisting() runs
    }

    if (ostoskori[i].tuote.id != tuoteID) {
        addNew(tuoteID, tuoteNimi, tuoteMaara, tuoteHinta); //this doesn't matter, it works.
        //break 

        //adding break here will stop the loop, 
        //which prevents the addToExisting() function running
    }
}
```

`ostoskori` is the json if you're wondering. As you can probably see, for each item the JSON has inside it, the more times `addNew()` will run.

So basically, if the JSON has a value with the same `id` as `tuoteID`, `addToExisting()` should run. If the JSON doesn't have a value same as `tuoteID`, run `addNew()`.

But how?

Comment: You can maintain an array of the ids that are being added and for the next obj insertion if the obj id is not there in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if the id already exists. The beauty of `some` is:

> If such an element is found, some immediately returns true.

If you're catering for older browsers there's a polyfill at the bottom of that page.

```
function hasId(data, id) {
  return data.some(function (el) {
    return el.tuote.id === id;
  });
}

hasId(data, '4'); // true
hasId(data, '14'); // false
```

So:

```
if (hasId(data, '4')) {
  addToExisting();
} else {
  addNew();
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/K9jDf/)

Comment: Seems like a perfect but yet a compact solution! One question about it though: If I type in `4` without the quotes, it will result in false. Is it because the `id` in the JSON not being an `ìnt`?

Comment: Yes. The id in the data (it stopped being JSON when you parsed it btw) is a string.

Comment: Ok, thanks, you saved my day! (I was just about to quit and throw my keyboard out of the window)

Comment: You can change the `===` to `==` and get away with passing in an integer. But I usually recommend using strict equality when you can.

Comment: Yep. This actually is a lighter option than my attempt! I can get rid of the for-loop now.